# Approximate tax savings if NYC employee moves residence from NYC to NJ?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york, new-jersey

How much would an employee expect to save on tax bill by moving residence from NYC to NJ, approximately?

Assume $200,000 income, single, no dependents, $0 for everything else (IRA, 401k, investments, etc).

Online tax estimators say tax bill for NYC is $72,000 and tax bill for NJ is $63,000. If working in one and living in the other, would the tax bill be closer to 72k or 63k?

Comment: Rental or homeowner?  As a state, NJ is #1 in property tax (NY is #9), though the exact rate is set at a county or municipal level.

Comment: Also note that renters _indirectly_ pay property tax through their rent.

Comment: for rental, not homeowner